# How to create JsonDeserializer that sets null to all Java object fields that equals to "" in JSON when using springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I am using spring boot, and I need to accept http request with application/json format. There are some params that equal to "" and I need to accept those param with null.

I know there are some similar questions but there is not any specific answer to those questions, I would be very appreciated if someone can give a specific explanation with code implementation.

====================================================================

**Here is my final code solution, hope that could help somebody.**

> ```
> @Configuration
> public class MessageConverterConfig{
>
>     @Bean
>     @Primary // Use this to shadow other objectmappers
>     public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
>         ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
>         objMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT,true);
>         return objMapper;
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you [jackson-issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/768)

Basically you need to create **custom deserializer** 
and then register it as Module to your ObjectMapper

Comment: I knew the deserializer can achieve it, but I want some more specific code implementations as example. And the Params may be any type in java such as enum type. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway.

Comment: But the example was given on string type, what if the type is enum? And where should I put the register module code, in a file with configuration annotation?

Comment: I am sorry but it looks like its something you need to figure out on your own. This is the time when you apply your programming skills and learn something new.